# URL Rewrite to different port on IIS 7.5

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rewrite, iis-7.5

I have an IIS server with diferents sites running on diferents ports, for example: site1 runs on port 8025, site2 on 8026, site3 on port 8027. I want to configure URL rewrite so the user only have to type the address site1.domain.com instead of site1.domain.com:8025.

I'm trying to do this using URL Rewrite module on IIS Console, but every time I get "error 404, site or directory not found". Is this possible this rewrite using this module or do I need to use a reverse proxy?

Thanks and best regards,
Amedina

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting to a different port works but the port will not be left out.

This rule will rewrite the request to port 8025 but the port will be included in the URL.

If that does not do what you want you will need to use Application Request Routing which as you probably suspect is a reverse proxy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the ARR can be running on the same server as the Web server?

Comment: You would do this using two web servers. There are a lot of diagrams on this page. http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis. What you are actually looking for might be this though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920073/iis7-url-rewrite-for-a-specific-port-only.